# How Create Sql String Format for (CC/FGLIC/2018/001)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch details based on string format like (**ABCD/2018/001**),
(**ABCDEFG/2018/00002**). I have no idea that how many texts before the slash.

```
SELECT  cp.CaseID, cp.BillNo, ca.CaseNo, ca.CaseName, ISNULL(cp.Balance,0) AS BalanceAmount, ISNULL(cp.TotalAmount,0) AS PaidAmount 
FROM  Cases ca  
LEFT JOIN  CasePayment cp ON cp.CaseID=ca.ID  
WHERE cp.BillNo LIKE '%ABC/2018/0001%'
```

[image]

Comment: are there always 2 slashes in that billno field?

Comment: Yes. There are only 2 slash

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to get those details which are matched to format. that's all.

Comment: It is not entirely clear, at least not to me, how the pattern is specified. What is the logic behind the expected format?

Comment: *There are only 2 slash* yet in your screenshot row 1, 3, 4, and 7 seem to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see, slash(/) is occurring two times in BillNo column, to do this you can use the like expression in `where` clause. For eg: `LIKE '%/%/%'`

Please try the below SQL:

```
SELECT  cp.CaseID, cp.BillNo, ca.CaseNo, ca.CaseName, ISNULL(cp.Balance,0) AS BalanceAmount, ISNULL(cp.TotalAmount,0) AS PaidAmount 
FROM  Cases ca  
LEFT JOIN  CasePayment cp ON cp.CaseID=ca.ID  
WHERE cp.BillNo LIKE '%/%/%';
```

Comment: Yeah, It's Great! Thanks for it.